# почему получается 0

Tags: java

`public static double HD1080W = ((1920-1366)/1366)*100;`
`public static double HD1080H = ((1080-768)/768)*100;`
*вывожу в консоль:*
экран:0.0x0.0
-как видите получается 0,а мне это не очень надо я пробовал ставить int вместо double но ни-к каким результатам это не привело...

**Прошу помочь,может я где-то недосмотрел...**

Comment: если кому интересно,я здесь пытаюсь вывести соотношение экранов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Java при делении целого числа на целое число получается целое число. В данном случае 0. Укажите компилятору, что заинтересованы в дробных значениях:

```
public static double HD1080W = ((1920.0-1366)/1366)*100;
public static double HD1080H = ((1080.0-768)/768)*100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы делите **целые** числа, они просто потом автоматически преобразуются в дробные, т.к. при выражении подобного типа явное преобразование не требуется. К литералам (вашим числам в коде) можно добавить **d** *(Пример:1920d-1366d...)*, тогда действия будут выполняться с дробными числами. Вот хорошая [статья](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/literals.php) про литералы. Также можно просто добавить точку с нулем, как в ответе выше.